# binding dynamic img src in vue

Tags: vue.js, binding

I want to bind my image src dynamically.
**my template:**

```
<template>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="img">
            <img v-bind:src="getImg" > 
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**I have a computed function:**

```
 getImg(){
            var img=this.project['img'];
            return require(`${img}`); // i am sure img exists
        }
```

but i got module not found error .

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module '../assets/projects/sample.jpg'
    at webpackContextResolve (eval at ./src/components sync recursive ^.*$ (app.js:1247), <anonymous>:15:11)
    at webpackContext (eval at ./src/components sync recursive ^.*$ (app.js:1247), <anonymous>:10:11)
    at Proxy.getImg (ProjectItem.vue?624f:26)
    at ComputedRefImpl.reactiveEffect [as effect] (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:42)
    at ComputedRefImpl.get value [as value] (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:790)
    at Object.get [as getImg] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5387)
    at Proxy.render (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/index.js?!./src/components/ProjectItem.vue?vue&type=template&id=210d7dcc&scoped=true&bindings={"project":"props","key":"props","getImg":"options"} (app.js:986), <anonymous>:21:19)
    at Proxy.eval (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:1154)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:535)
    at componentEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4286)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand that `require()` (or `import()`) is handled by Webpack at build time. Webpack can't execute your code and possibly know what the value at runtime will be. Take a look at the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import) (it's about `import()` but `require()` [is almost same](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression))

Simple fix would be to make only part of the path dynamic so Webpack gets at leas some hint what file should be made available...

Try to replace

```js
return require(`${img}`);
```

by

```js
return require(`../assets/projects/${img}`);
```

and store just the file name in the `img` variable...